# Loading html into page element (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that will have a bar at the top of certain webpages.  If I have my content script like this:

```
$('body').prepend('<div id="topbar"><h1>test</h1></div>');
```

everything looks good, but what I ultimately want is something like this:

```
$('body').prepend('<div id="topbar"></div>');
$('#topbar').load('topbar.html');
```

where topbar.html is:

```
<h1>test</h1>
```

When I change it to this, though, the webpage is clobbered.  Most of the content disappears, and I just end up seeing some of the ads.  I can't even see the 'test' header.  I've checked to make sure there's no other 'topbar' id on the page.  What's wrong?

Comment: Where is `topbar.html` located? Chrome-Extension or web-side?

Comment: It's in the chrome extension's directory

Comment: Well, `.load` uses AJAX to load in files to elements, and I am pretty sure you cannot load via AJAX local chrome files.

Comment: I just used code that looks almost identical to this..  I added "web_accessible_resources": [...] to my manifest.json file and it worked perfectly..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

URL of a file inside an extenion folder has the following format:

```
chrome-extension://<ID>/topbar.html
```

You can get this path by running:

```
chrome.extension.getURL("topbar.html")
```

Now if you try to do:

```
$('#topbar').load(chrome.extension.getURL("topbar.html"));
```

it wouldn't let you because of cross-origin policy. Background pages don't have this limitation, so you would need to load HTML there and pass result to a content script:

**content_script.js**:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "read_file"}, function(html){
    $("#topbar").html(html);
});
```

**background.html**:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.cmd == "read_file") {
        $.ajax({
            url: chrome.extension.getURL("topbar.html"),
            dataType: "html",
            success: sendResponse
        });
    }
})
```

In a real world you probably would read topbar.html only once and then reuse it.

Comment: The $.get(chrome.extension.getURL("topbar.html"), function(topbarContent){ 
...
  }, 'html'); bit works fine for me - I don't see any cross-origin errors in the console.

Comment: Should specify `web_accessible_resources` in the manifest. See: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources

Comment: are you sure @VladIliescu...? I mean... did you get it as html or some object?

Comment: Please note that the `getURL()` method is now deprecated. "Non-standart. Expect poor cross-browser support" according to [Browser support for Javascript APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_support_for_JavaScript_APIs#extension)

Answer (score 6):

While the above solution does work, one thing to pay attention to is that you need to return true from the event handler so that the communication port can still be available after the $.ajax call succeeds.

see below for more information.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=307034

Comment: If you want to expand on another person's answer it is best to leave a comment on their answer instead of making a second one.

Answer (score 6):

Pure js solution.

In your `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  # [...]
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "resources": ["topbar.html"]
  }]
}
```

In your `content.js`:

```
async function load_toolbar() {
  let newElement = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<div id="toolbar"></div>', 'text/html').body.childNodes[0];
  let toolbar_url = chrome.runtime.getURL("toolbar.html");

  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(newElement);
  document.getElementById("toolbar").innerHTML = await (await fetch(toolbar_url)).text();
}

load_toolbar();
```

Comment: This is the most helpful answer. Works great.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, now in 2020, **chrome.extension.onRequest** is deprecated and causes an error when loading the extension.
Instead, **chrome.runtime.sendMessage** should be used.
For **content.js**, the code would now be:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({cmd: "read_file"}, function(html){
    $("#topbar").html(html);
});
```

and for **background.js** the code would now be:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.cmd == "read_file") {
        $.ajax({
            url: chrome.extension.getURL("topbar.html"),
            dataType: "html",
            success: sendResponse
        });
       return true;
    }
})
```

be sure to note the 'return true' after the ajax, that tripped me up

Comment: Ensure to add, make sure to include "topbar.html" in web_accessible_resources of manifest.json
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources