# Creating a chrome extension to grab all page HTML

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to create a chrome extension to grab all website data. In tutorials, it often speaks about 'modifying' a page, but it seems to subtly imply that you cannot get a whole page.

I found one [chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) which is [pageCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture) which allows ALL resources from a page to be saved. Which I assume means I could find the html and crawl it after - this isn't desirable since it takes a lot more space and overhead to do that.

I'd prefer if there was some way to crawl the active tab. [The tab API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) allows you to get the current Tab but the current tab doesn't seem to have a content attribute.

There must be a better way to do that. Anyone know how to get the current page HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the source HTML of the current page from chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684454/getting-the-source-html-of-the-current-page-from-chrome-extension)

Comment: I should say that I'm looking for a content script solution to the problem, I'll update when I've created it.

Comment: could u please share  the  tutorial link with me?

Answer (score -1):

I think this answer will help you :
[Loading html into page element (chrome extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643263/loading-html-into-page-element-chrome-extension)

I have another solution may help you, so if you want you can save the websites in you chrome bookmarks, and then fetch all of the data using:

```
var uploadUrls_bm_urls ='';
var uploadUrls_temp = '';
var maxUrls = "1000";

/* Fetch all user bookmark from browser  */
/* @param object parentNode - the parent node of bookmark tree */

function fetch_bookmarks(parentNode) {
    parentNode.forEach(function(bookmark) {
        if(! (bookmark.url === undefined || bookmark.url === null)) {
            uploadUrls_bm_urls = uploadUrls_bm_urls + '"' +  bookmark.url + '",';
            if(uploadUrls_bm_urls.length <= maxUrls )
              uploadUrls_temp = uploadUrls_bm_urls;
        }
        if (bookmark.children) {
            fetch_bookmarks(bookmark.children);
        }
    });
}
```

and after that you can iterate over all the urls and use the "load" function as in the link above ( [Loading html into page element (chrome extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643263/loading-html-into-page-element-chrome-extension)
).

Let me know if this helped you or not.

Thanks